# Photon Fusion multiplayer scene already has Network Object. How to add it to simulation

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, fusion

I am using Photon Fusion for multiplayer purposes and I have a game object with Network object script. Its not initialized as other objects which I spawn.

I can do Fusion.Runner.Attach() but it then attaches the object to a player and this will only work for Host/Server